# How to search in field collection item?

Tags: search, entities

I want the Drupal Default Search to look into Field Collection items.

I currently have a field_resources collection with a field_description and a field_file, and the search should be looking into both.

Is this possible? What simple alternative could I use instead? An external search module seems a bit overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As say in [Search interface](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search.module/group/search/7) the search system already indexes all visible output of a node; i.e., everything displayed normally by hook_view() and hook_node_view().

You can activate and configure in the display settings of your content type the custom display "Search index" than will be used for indexing.

If this doesn't works in you case, you can implement [hook_node_update_index](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_update_index/7) to add any information you want on the node before is indexed.

Answer (score 0):

[Search API Attachments](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_attachments) Module helps you search through file attached in field collection

> This module is an add-on to the Search API which allows the indexing
>   and searching of attachments.

Comment: The question is about Drupal core Search.